# what is the difference between `>> /dev/stderr` (with the white space) and `>&2`?

Tags: bash, ssh, io-redirection, stderr

In bash.

I am having some difficulty to determine what I should use?

all my scripts use ">>/dev/stderr"

at bash prompt, if I try:
`echo test >>/dev/stderr` works
`echo test >> /dev/stderr` works
`echo test >/dev/stderr` works
`echo test > /dev/stderr` works

`echo test >>&2` FAILS!
`echo test >> &2` FAILS!
`echo test >&2` works
`echo test > &2` FAILS!

I am willing to change all my scripts to `>&2`.

It seems to also have a big effect over ssh (after `su SomeUser`) where `>>/dev/stderr` will not work at all (permission denied), only `>&2` will work.

Comment: can you show an example of the ssh error? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller you are right, It is only after `su` that the problem happens, updated the question

Comment: @AquariusPower, ...to explain that discrepancy, by the way: with `su -c 'some command'`, that command is run by `/bin/sh`, not `bash`, so bash-specific behavior (such as simulating `/dev/stderr` for redirection purposes when not available) isn't guaranteed to be present.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`>& n` is shell syntax to [directly duplicate a file descriptor](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Duplicating-File-Descriptors). File descriptor 2 is stderr; that's how that one works. You can duplicate other file descriptors as well, not just stderr. You can't use append mode here because duplicating a file descriptor never truncates (even if your stderr is a file) and `>&` is one token, that's why you can't put a space inside it—but `>& 2` works.

`>> name` is a different permitted syntax, where `name` is a file name (and the token is `>>`). In this case, you're using the file name `/dev/stderr`, which by OS-specific handling (on Linux, it's a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/2`) also means standard error. Append and truncate mode both wind up doing the same thing when stderr is a terminal because that can't be truncated. If your standard error is a file, however, it *will* be truncated:

```
anthony@Zia:~$ bash -c 'echo hi >/dev/stderr; echo bye >/dev/stderr' 2>/tmp/foo
anthony@Zia:~$ cat /tmp/foo
bye
```

If you're seeing an error with `/dev/stderr` over ssh, it's possible the server admin has applied some security measure preventing that symlink from working. (E.g., you can't access `/proc` or `/dev`). While I'd expect either to cause all kinds of weird breakage, using the duplicate file descriptor syntax is a perfectly reasonable (and likely slightly more efficient) approach. Personally I prefer it.

Comment: I was having a big trouble trying to replicate that truncate problem I had before (otherwise I would have added that to the question hehe), the reason I changed everything to use `>>`, thx for pointing that out! Also, I missed a step `su SomeUser` after connecting thru ssh.

Comment: this `bash -c 'echo hi >&2; echo bye >&2' 2>/tmp/foo;cat /tmp/foo` wont truncate tho! (even with `2>&1 |tee /tmp/foo`) what is perfect for logging, and will work perfectly after I change it all to `>&2`. So I guess only a directly file usage `/dev/stderr` allows truncating, not the duplicated descriptor, cool thx!

Comment: @AquariusPower correct, duplicate file descriptor never truncates. That's in the first paragraph, maybe I need to highlight it somehow?

Comment: not needed, I am slow sometimes ehehe

Comment: One aspect in which this is (slightly) literally incorrect: bash reads `/dev/stderr` as FD 2 for redirections, even when the OS doesn't provide any literal `/dev` entry by that name. That said, this is very much a bashism, and is not functionality that POSIX sh provides (and thus will often not be available on the other side of a ssh connection to a system with an unknown `/bin/sh` implementation).

Comment: @AquariusPower, au contraire -- your example *does* truncate, during the `2>/tmp/foo` redirection run before the `bash -c` instance is exec'd; if you start with a non-empty file and run your full example, you'll see its contents replaced with (both) `hi` and `bye` lines. You're correct that `>&2` never truncates.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy according to the docs, that's only when `/dev/stderr` doesn't exist. I'm including bash's fallback behavior in "OS-specific handling".

Comment: @derobert, ...ahh. I tend to read "OS-specific" to imply that something is provided by the OS itself, as opposed to the shell -- but understand where you're coming from now.

Comment: This answer can be improved. >& is one token not two and there in lies OP's confusion.

Comment: re: highlighting.  I like to **bold** key points in my answers for the benefit of people skimming.  Especially for longer answers, but this one is just barely big enough.

Comment: @Joshua added to the answer, thanks for pointing out that I'd failed to actually explain why the OP's attempt with a space didn't work.

Comment: Maybe it would be worth noting that `[n]>&word` is standardized in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_06) and therefore portable.

Answer (score 7):

The failure cases occur because the [bash syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Duplicating-File-Descriptors) for using `&` in redirections specifies a single `>`, and requires that it exists directly adjacent to the `&` sign:

> [n]>&word

Answer (score 2):

Use `'>'` to redirect (truncates if exists) or `'>>'` (appends if exists).

Use `'>&'` to duplicate a stream, for instance, if you want standard output AND standard error in the same file, you redirect to file `'> output.log'` and also error with `'2>&'`

```
myjob.sh > output.log 2>&
```