# Prevent truncation of file with output redirection via /dev/stdout

Tags: linux, files, io-redirection

I have a program that I want to execute and gather its output in a file. However, while running the program opens `/dev/stdout` (i.e., `/proc/self/fd/0`) and truncates it, which removes all content from the file that accumulates the output.

This can be reproduced easily with a small shell script:

```
sh -c "echo 1; echo 2 > /dev/stdout ; echo 3" >> test.txt
```

The result of this command is that `test.txt` contains `2` and `3` (this is also discussed in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331731/15398)). I would like it to contain `1`, `2`, and `3`.

Further information:

- The executed program is not under my control. I know that the problem would not occur if it would do `>> /dev/stdout`, but I cannot change that.
- I know that it works if I add a `cat` like this: `... | cat >> test.txt`. However, I would prefer a solution without the overhead of an additional process (this is for benchmarking).
- `chattr +a test.txt` might be a solution but requires root. I am just a regular user.
- I am actually using a container to execute the program and the output redirection is configured outside of the container. So if there is some solution that requires specific configuration of a container, this would be possible.
- Of course, the problem also exists for programs that write to `/dev/stderr` or directly use `/proc/self/fd/{0,1}`. I am looking for a general solution and just simplified the question.

In summary, I hope there is some way how to configure the redirection or the file descriptor or some other way to prevent truncation of `/proc/self/fd/0` even if it points to a file.

Comment: You can't change that -- it's a "feature" of linux that the `/dev/fd/` &co will open the files from scratch, instead of just dup'ing the fds. I don't think the extra `cat` will make any difference, but you could also use a [faster cat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/469779/308316) if that's really a problem. It would probably help if you gave an example more close to your actual problem -- maybe someone familiar with the exact container technology you're using could help you.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks for your response. Seems I need to use something like cat. The container technology I am using is standard Linux namespaces, configured by my own tool, not sure whether more details would be helpful. Basically, if there is any way to make the example from the question work, either directly or by wrapping it in a call to `unshare(1)` with whatever parameters, I could adapt the solution for my use case. Even if one would need C code to call stuff like `prctl(2)` or use seccomp that would also be ok.

Comment: I can't reproduce this effect with `bash` running in POSIX mode on OpenBSD. I suppose has something to do with how Linux, _specifically_, handles the redirection and/or file descriptors.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, seems plausible, at least on the NetBSD I have here `/dev/stdout` is a character device, whereas Linux provides these symbolic links to the original file.